# Can not download Laravel UI package

Tags: laravel, user-interface, download, composer-php, uri

I want to download Laravel UI package via composer and I have got this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like due to internet issue you can't access packagists site (which composer uses to get the packages) which is causing the installation to fail.

Comment: yeah you are right , I have tried vpn and it works , Thank you bro

Answer (score 0):

run a fresh composer create-project laravel/laravel  command, copy replace your composer.json content with the old projects composer.json. Do the same with .env file
and run composer install. then u can run "composer require/laravel/ui"